# How to store dd/MM/yyyy Datetime types into Database using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a Inventory project but I can't save **Datetime** datatypes like dd/MM/yyyy into Database. I know Database uses yyyy-MM-dd as standard Datetime but it also accepts MM-dd-yyyy(I think compiler converts it to yyyy-MM-dd).

This is what I have:

**Model**

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*Ingrese una fecha.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name ="FECHA")]
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Entrada.Fecha, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Entrada.Fecha, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Entrada.InventarioId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

When clicking the submit button it doesn't add to database, but when I write any Datetime with **mm/dd/yyyy**(For example 08/21/2019) type, it submits to database. I can't find solution on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
bool parsed = false;
DateTime outDate;
parsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(inputDate, "dd-MM- 
 yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, 
 out outDate);

 if(parsed)
 {
  usr.DogumTarihi = outDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
  }
 else
 {
   // Invalid date has been passed
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with *DateTime* and not *string*, the way the database <s>stores</s> displays the date will be **yyyy-MM-dd**. Sometimes if the date is not sent properly and seeing as your *DateTime* field is not nullable, it send the value *01/01/0001* (annoying right) so this is what i do...
In the model,

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, NullDisplayText = "NULL")]
```

In the view, i have

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Entrada.Fecha, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Enter Date", id = "Date", autocomplete = "off" })
```

and in the date picker js options,

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
        });
    });
```

This way, date is stored how database is configured and it is however displayed in the format *dd/MM/yyyy*. I know it does not answer the question of storing the date in the format you want but this way, you can DISPLAY the date in the format you want, both during submission, editing and displaying it.

Comment: _the way the database stores the date will be yyyy-MM-dd._ - The database does not store datetimes in any format.  They are stored as 2 integers. The first integer is the number of days before or after the base date of 1900/01/01. The second integer stores the number of clock ticks after midnight, each tick is 1/300 of a second.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Wrong choice of words, I meant display.